# Symfony2 Login ajax translate error message

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I would like to translate in my ajax login error messages.
I am using FOSUserBundle, and I would take advantage of the translation files I properly overwritten folder Resources/translations.

My AthenticationHandler.php:

```
class AuthenticationHandler
implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface,
       AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{

protected $router;
protected $security;
protected $userManager;
protected $service_container;

public function __construct(RouterInterface $router,SecurityContext $security, $userManager, $service_container)
{
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->security = $security;
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
    $this->service_container = $service_container;

}
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        //...
    }
    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('anag_new'));
}
public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception) {

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $error = $exception->getMessage();
        $result = array('success' => false, 'message' => $request->get('translator')->trans($error, array(), 'FOSUserBundle'));
        $response = new Response(json_encode($result));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

}

But return this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function trans() on a non-object in /var/www/MyBusiness/src/My/UserBundle/Handler/AuthenticationHandler.php
```

How do I translate the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$request->get(string $key, mixed $default = null, type $deep = false)`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_get) is for getting parameters from GET, PATH, POST, COOKIE. You are trying to get a "translator" parameter, which probably doesn't exist. So `null` is returned and you call `trans()` on a non-object.

Simply inject the "translator" service in your `AuthenticationHandler` (in the constructor, probably). Or get it from the service container, as it's available in your class:

```php
$translator = $this->service_container->get('translator');

// ...
$result = array(
    'success' => false,
    'message' => $translator->trans($error, array(), 'FOSUserBundle')
);
```